# Open pdf files format with python

Tags: python, pdf

I try to open 100 pdf files with python 2.7 with this code:

```
import arcpy,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"D:\desktop"
pattern = '*.pdf'
counter = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        os.startfile(rootPath)
        counter = counter + 1
print counter
```

as a result the rootPath folder opened and python print the number of pdf files:

```
>>> 
39
>>>
```

No pdf files opened. I search in the forum and didn't find any question with answers to my request. Thanks for any help

Comment: are your sure `rootPath` returns you the name of the PDF file? I see you defind rootPath as `D:\desktop` and its not even the name of the PDF you're trying to open

Comment: yes  i sure it return

Comment: Try an onteractive python shell. Copy the full path of an existing pdf file, with proper backlash escaping (i.e. `D:\desktop` becomes `D:\\desktop`) , and try: `import os; os.startfile(pdf_file_path)`. Does Adobe reader / other PDF viewer come up? If not, the MIME type registry is suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying to do, but `os.startfile` will open up adobe pdf reader (or any other reader that's set as default reader)... here how i managed to do that and it seems to be working.

```
import os

rootPath = "D:\\desktop"
counter = 0
for file in os.listdir(rootPath):
    if file.endswith('.pdf'):
        os.startfile("%s/%s" %(rootPath, file))
        counter = counter + 1
print counter
```

or without much editing your main code

```
import arcpy,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"D:\desktop"
pattern = '*.pdf'
counter = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        os.startfile("%s/%s" %(rootPath,filename))
        counter = counter + 1
print counter
```

Comment: with second option i get error : WindowsError: [Error 2] : 'D:\\desktop/Hebrewbooks_org_19055.pdf'

Comment: @newGIS hmm still works for me without errors, probably your PDF is corrupted? you can stick with the first solution thought

Answer (score 0):

Your are always calling

```
os.startfile(rootPath)
```

where `rootPath` is only `"D:\desktop"`. You must call `os.startfile` with the path to the PDF file as the argument.

```
os.startfile("{}/{}".format(rootPath, file))
```